# How to set a range of delta in power.t.test

Tags: r

I want to run the power.t.test with each delta value to calculate the necessary number of samples and then save it to a value in the reps vector to replace an NA. I tried to make a for loop, but it would only change where reps was being saved and used the same delta value every time. Is there a way to have the for loop call different values of delta even though it's inside of another function?

```
delta = c(.25,.5,.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2)
reps = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
reps[1] <- power.t.test(n = NULL,
                   delta = delta[1],
                   sd = pop_sd,
                   sig.level = 0.01,
                   power = 0.90,
                   type = 'paired',
                   alternative = 'two.sided'
                      )$n
ans <- data.frame(delta / pop_sd,reps)
ans
```

Edit: Here's my for loop that's gotten me the closest I think.

```
for (x in delta){
  reps[1:8] <- power.t.test(n = NULL,  # make sure to fill in ALL of the ?
                       delta = delta[x],
                       sd = pop_sd,
                       sig.level = 0.01,
                       power = 0.90,
                       type = 'paired',
                       alternative = 'two.sided'
                          )$n
}
```

Edit 2: I figured out my original mistake. I needed to use `for (i in 1:8)` to call indexed numbers from `delta` and `reps`.

```
for (i in 1:8){
  reps[i] <- power.t.test(n = NULL,  # make sure to fill in ALL of the ?
                       delta = delta[i],
                       sd = pop_sd,
                       sig.level = 0.01,
                       power = 0.90,
                       type = 'paired',
                       alternative = 'two.sided'
                          )$n
}
```

Comment: Let's see your `for` loop. Sounds like a typo that's probably easy to explain and fix.

Comment: I added my for code above. Didn't know how to add it to a comment.

Comment: Adding it above is much better than adding it in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
tmp_reps = lapply(1:length(delta), function(x){
           power.t.test(n = NULL,
           delta = delta[x],
           sd = pop_sd,
           sig.level = 0.01,
           power = 0.90,
           type = 'paired',
           alternative = 'two.sided')$n
})

reps <- unlist(tmp_reps)
ans <- data.frame(delta / pop_sd, reps)
```

Comment: That worked! I'm pretty new to r and hadn't thought to use the lapply. Glad to add another function to the tool belt! Thanks!